# Edit text cursor not visible after setting SetCursorVisible(false) and click again

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have one requirement, After entering the text in editbox then click the virtual keyboard DONE(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) now the cursor is invisible [i am using editText.setCursorVisible(false)]. Now the problem is again i click the editbox cursor is not visible, But text is taking into the editbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);//this brought back my cursor after setting focusable false.
```

instead of

```
edittext.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cursor visible again, in your onClick listener of your EditText.

Try these two methods in your edittext onClick listener.

```
edittext.setFocusable(true);
edittext.setCursorVisible(true);
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

place this attribute in the edittext widget.

```
        android:cursorVisible="false"
```

an then place this code in oncreate() of mainactivity.

```
Edittext searchView;
searchView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
searchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            searchView.setCursorVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Note::i have written this for futures queries..hope this is i think not required for this qs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe invalidating the view?

```
editText.invalidate()
```